# swapping uiimageviews in iphone sdk

Tags: ios4, uiimageview, swap

I need a requirement like some playing cards.For example we are having 13 cards we will showing them in a line.

Now i should be able to swap the cards manually.Like if i drag the card from position 8 and drop it in position 4 then card in postion 4 should move to position 5 ,card in postion 5 should move to position 6,card in postion 6 should move to position 7,card in postion 7 should move to position 8.

Similarly ,if i drag the card from position 3 and dropped it in position 9 then card in position 3 should move to 9,card in postion 4 should move to position 3,card in postion 5 should move to position 4,card in postion 6 should move to position 5,card in postion 7 should move to position 6,card in postion 8 should move to position 7 and card in postion 9 should move to position 8.

Similarly the process should continue.

Can any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Mru

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any easy answers to your question. You would need to create your own custom views and write animation code to solve this problem.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/moveme/introduction/intro.html

The Move me example from apple linked above is a good start.